# Favorites from list of huge drop-down menu for each user php,jquery,ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, list, dropdown

I have list of huge drop-down. I want the user to add or remove and make their list as favorite from the original list.I am not sure what are ways to do do it? any ideas ? also its per user different. So storing it in DB wont work.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You will have to store the favorites somewhere.. Either in the database or in [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). A cookie could also do the job, but I would personally go for one of the two first. It really depends on your requirement. Local storage might be removed by user or if user uses a different browser / device, the favorites are gone.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: I understand.I am not asking for code here but asking ideas how to peruse ahead in my coding.

Comment: There are 2 options to store information  **1 client side (temporary)** using **localStorage or Cookies**, **2 server side (permanent)**  using **db or cache** i would prefer 2nd option!

Comment: Thanks all for suggestions.chose to go with storing it in DB.thanks again